# Не проходит последние тесты, задача C++

Tags: c++, олимпиада

В классических ролевых играх есть 3 стандартных класса: Воин (Warrior), Маг (Mage), Вор (Rogue). Для каждого из классов важен определённый атрибут: для Воина - сила, для Мага - интеллект, для Вора - ловкость.

По значению атрибутов определите предпочтительный класс для персонажа.

Входные данные. Три неотрицательных целых числа через пробел - атрибуты персонажа: сила, интеллект, ловкость.
Формат результата
Выходные данные. Необходимо вывести строку с названием предпочтительного класса (см. примеры), если предпочтительный класс выявить невозможно вывести Any

1)
Входные данные

14 5 5

Результат работы

Recommended class for character (14,5,5) is Warrior.

2)

Входные данные

14 21 1

Результат работы

Recommended class for character (14,21,1) is Mage.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    unsigned long long W, M, R;
    cin>>W>>M>>R;
    if (W>M && W>R) { 
        cout<<"Recommended class for character"<<" "<<"("<<W<<","<<M<<","<<R<<")"<<" "<<"is Warrior.";
    }
    else if (M>W && M>R) {
        cout<<"Recommended class for character"<<" "<<"("<<W<<","<<M<<","<<R<<")"<<" "<<"is Mage.";
    }
    else if (R>M && R>W) {
        cout<<"Recommended class for character"<<" "<<"("<<W<<","<<M<<","<<R<<")"<<" "<<"is Rogue.";
    }
    else if (R==M || M==W || W==R) {
        cout<<"Any";
    }
}
```

Comment: может `cout<<"Recommended class for character"<<" "<<"("<<W<<","<<M<<","<<R<<")"<<" "<<"is Any.";`?

Comment: Спасибо большое, очень сильно тупанул капец